# Django middleware advised not to use request.POST why?

Tags: python, django, backend, middleware

"Accessing request.POST inside middleware before the view runs or in process_view() will prevent any view running after the middleware from being able to modify the upload handlers for the request, and should normally be avoided."

This is from the django documentation. First of all, if I just read the POST, without changing that, how does it even know and how does it prevent the view from doing it's business and second, how is a CsrfViewMiddleware different in that sense?

Comment: If you want to ask questions about the docs, it's helpful to link to them, so people can see any context (and make sure it's not a 12-year-old version, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

The warning comes from [this ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/16384) and [this](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/613).

---

> Django currently parses the POST data lazily, but middlware might try to access POST on a request and trigger parsing, even though the function itself never touches POST.

---

> That would put high load on the machine if the POST data is rather large ...

---

> It means that the view will be unable to set any custom upload handlers, perform custom parsing of the request body, or enforce permission checks prior to file uploads being accepted.

And the difference about CsrfViewMiddleware is stated clearly right below the said warning in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/middleware/#process-view):

> The CsrfViewMiddleware ... provides the csrf_exempt() and
>   csrf_protect() decorators which allow views to explicitly control at what point the CSRF validation should
>   occur.